# Showing shell Toast notification on receiving message

Tags: notifications, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to make a chat app using XMPP protocol. The app is working fine except it doesn't show message notification when the app is in background. In Android I have used a Service for this purpose, however in Windows Phone I couldn't find anything similar to this.

I am trying Background Tasks for this, but as far as I have understood, they're made to run on prespecified trigger and I cannot add any custom trigger to it. In Android I have put my socket connection and parsing message calls in the service itself so that they can run on background too and the socket doesn't get closed even when the app is stopped.

So my question is, is there any similar way to do it in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT, not silverlight) or if  Background Task is the only option, can you suggest a way to implement the notification functionality. I don't need the exact code, I just need a push to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You cannot run a network connection in background.

Suggested way is using PushNotifications:

1. Either directly with a Toast Notification
2. Or with a PushTrigger to handle a [Raw Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj676791.aspx), work out what to do
   with it (who was it from, prepare data, etc.) and then create a ShellToast from it. Adds flexibility and improves user experience, but is quite complex.

Known downside: You have to use a server.

Only workarounds: Background-Tasks that checks for new messages about every 30 Minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use a separate server just for sending push notifications. So I suppose I should use background tasks.

Comment: Seems so... Keep in mind you only get notified about every thirty minutes then. Not the best for a chat...